# ReactJS: How To Call Class From External Javascript File

Tags: reactjs

I use CDN file:

```
"use strict"; 

class Scroll{
    constructor(){
        this._lastPos = 0
        this._flags = []
        this._dead = false
        this.start()
    }

    .....
```

I want to call `var x = new Scroll();` How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `export` keyword.

```js
"use strict"; 

export class Scroll{
    constructor(){
        this._lastPos = 0
        this._flags = []
        this._dead = false
        this.start()
    }

    .....
```

and in your other file put in

```js
import {Scroll} from "ScrollClass.js"

/* code */
```

or use a default export

```js
"use strict"; 

class Scroll{
    constructor(){
        this._lastPos = 0
        this._flags = []
        this._dead = false
        this.start()
    }

    .....
}

export default Scroll;
```

```js
import Scroll from "ScrollClass.js"

/* code */
```

Here are the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)